# Steak house in Amsterdam?

Tags: food-and-drink, recommendations, restaurants, amsterdam, socializing

I'm looking for a steak house in Amsterdam that has a reasonable price range (absolutely not more than 30 euro for a big steak), is located in a central location, does not require any reservation, has some good beers to choose, and is not a tourist-trap. It should also have a wide range of various animals to choose from. At least beef, pork, veal, lamb and ostrich is a must. I would be very happy if I can also choose the weight of my steak. At least 300 grams have to be available, 500 would be a plus. Additionally, it would be a plus if it is also frequently visited by local girls.

Comment: Did you go to a steakhouse in the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is easy: [Piet de Leeuw](http://www.diningcity.nl/pietdeleeuw/)

If you like garlic you might also consider [The garlic queen](http://www.garlicqueen.nl/). The options regarding steak are not huge, but you'll never forget the experience